# Hiding Drawer item Using Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigationview

I am using navigation component along with navigation drawer. If a user login with FirebaseAuth in my `LoginFragment` I want to hide login/signup menu from navigation drawer.
Can anyone tell me how could I do that?

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a user login with FirebaseAuth in my LoginFragment I want to hide login/signup menu from navigation drawer

You can get the menu from the `NavigationView` attached to the navigation drawer and use [`removeItem(id)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#removeItem(int)) to remove a particular item:

```
if (userLoggedIn) { // Set that to your logic when the user logged in.
    removeItem(R.id.singup); // adjust that to the id you set to sign up
    removeItem(R.id.login); // adjust that to the id you set to login 
}

public removeItem(int id) {
    NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.foo); // Add your NavigationView id
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    if (menu.findItem(id) != null) // Make sure that the item exists in the menu
        menu.removeItem(id); 
}
```

UPDATE

> navigation drawer is in my MainActivity

To access activity from the fragment use `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()` like:

```
((MainActivity) requireActivity()).removeItem(R.id.login); // adjust that to the id you set to sign up
((MainActivity) requireActivity()).removeItem(R.id.signup); // adjust that to the id you set to login
```

Comment: navigation drawer is in my MainActivity.

Comment: @EhasanPial you can use `requireActivity()` to get the activity from the fragment.. It is not that good that in terms of performance that you restart the activity to disable a menu item.. Please have a look at the UPDATE section in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this problem.
When a user is logged in via LoginFragment then I reload MainActivity.
Again when a user sign out via Navigation Drawer then again I reload MainAcitvity.

`startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class)); getActivity().finish();`